# What does it mean in ebib when a field of an entry is preceeded with an asterisk '*'?

Tags: latex, buffers, bibtex

When viewing entries in a database in `ebib`, some fields of some entries are marked with an asterisk (`*`). In my case, these are usually `year` or `month` field. I don't see a rhyme or reason to the types of entries, nor can I see any common error or mistake distinguishing these marked fields from other similar ones in either the same or other entries.

I know that the manual says `+` is used for multi-line entries, and these are certainly not those.

What does this asterisk mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citation from the section "String Definitions" in the info manual of Ebib:

> Having defined ‘@string’ definitions, there must of course be a way
>   to use them.  Just giving a field a string abbreviation as value will
>   not do, because Ebib puts braces around the value that you enter when it
>   writes the ‘.bib’ file, so that BibTeX will not recognise the
>   abbreviation, and will not expand it.  BibTeX will only recognise an
>   abbreviation if it appears in the ‘.bib’ file outside of any braces.
>
> To accomplish this, you must mark a field’s value as special.  A
>   special field is a field whose value is not surrounded by braces when
>   the database is saved, so that BibTeX recognises it as an abbreviation.
>   To mark a field special, press ‘r’.  **An asterisk** will appear before the
>   field, indicating that has no braces.  Pressing ‘r’ again will change
>   the field back to normal.  If you press ‘r’ on a field that does not
>   have a value yet, Ebib will ask you for one.